# %like% with multiple patterns in r

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr

Is it possible to use multiple pattern with %like% in a nested ifelse? If not, what would be the alternative?

```
fruits<-c("apple", "pineapple", "grape", "avocado","banana")

color <-c("red","yellow","purple", "green","yellow")

mydata = data.frame(fruits=fruits,color=color ) 


mydata %>%
  mutate(group = ifelse(fruits %like% c("%pple%","%vocado%"), "group 1",
                           ifelse(fruits %like% c("%anana%","%grape%"), "group 2", "group 3")))
```

When I try the code above, I get the following error:

```
Warning messages:
1: In grep(pattern, levels(vector)) :
  argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In grep(pattern, levels(vector)) :
  argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Any guidance is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Not sure which package you're using, but if you are using the `DescTools` version of `%like%`, they also have a `%like any%` function. But if you're using the `data.table` or `Tmisc` package versions, I don't see an equivalent.

Comment: Are you using `data.table::%like%`? Those patterns you're using are not regex, they're more SQL-esque.

Comment: Please let us know what version of `%like%` you are using. If you're not sure, put `?"%like%"` in your console, and look at the top left of the documentation page that pops up to see the package name in {braces}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can `sapply` on the patterns and do row-summing to find what you need.

Notes:

- I'm converting your SQL-esque patterns to regex here.
- when using `dplyr`, it's probably better to use its `if_else`, as this version better guards against different class outputs (as well as some other issues with base `ifelse`).
- Since `%like%` is just an infix operator for the `like` function (in `data.table`, at least), I'm using the latter (pre-fix version) here for clarity.

```r
sapply(c(".*apple.*", ".*vocado.*"), like, vector = fruits)
#      .*apple.* .*vocado.*
# [1,]      TRUE      FALSE
# [2,]      TRUE      FALSE
# [3,]     FALSE      FALSE
# [4,]     FALSE       TRUE
# [5,]     FALSE      FALSE
rowSums(sapply(c(".*apple.*", ".*vocado.*"), like, vector = fruits)) > 0
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

That's what we need, a vector of `logical`. I'll make a helper function for that.

```r
mylike <- function(x, ptns) rowSums(sapply(ptns, like, vector = x)) > 0
mylike(fruits, c(".*apple.*", ".*vocado.*"))
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
mydata %>%
  mutate(
    group = if_else(mylike(fruits, c(".*apple.*", ".*vocado.*")), "group 1",
                    if_else(mylike(fruits, c(".*anana.*",".*grape.*")), "group 2", "group 3"))
  )
#      fruits  color   group
# 1     apple    red group 1
# 2 pineapple yellow group 1
# 3     grape purple group 2
# 4   avocado  green group 1
# 5    banana yellow group 2
```

However, when I see nested `ifelse`/`if_else`, I suggest `case_when`, as it is much more readable, especially when the number of conditions increases.

```r
mydata %>%
  mutate(
    group = case_when(
      mylike(fruits, c(".*apple.*", ".*vocado.*")) ~ "group 1",
      mylike(fruits, c(".*anana.*",".*grape.*"))   ~ "group 2",
      TRUE                                         ~ "group 3"
    )
  )
#      fruits  color   group
# 1     apple    red group 1
# 2 pineapple yellow group 1
# 3     grape purple group 2
# 4   avocado  green group 1
# 5    banana yellow group 2
```

---

If you already have a set of SQL patterns and don't want to translate them all to regexes, here's a quick helper function based on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/36864/42300:

```r
# https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/36864/42300
sql2regex <- function(ptn) {
  paste0(
    "^",
    gsub("_", ".",
         gsub("(?<!\\[)%(?!\\])", ".*", ptn, perl = TRUE)),
    "$")
}
```

It tries to be smart to not convert `[%]`, which is one way to "escape" a percent and go for its literal (ref: http://www.sqlserver.info/syntax/sql-server-like-with-percent-literal/). However, even though `[%` may seem incomplete, this is not translated correctly to `^[.*$`, it instead remains `^[%$`, which will fail. Again, this is just a quick-hack helper function.

```r
mydata %>%
  mutate(
    group = case_when(
      mylike(fruits, sql2regex(c("%pple%","%vocado%"))) ~ "group 1",
      mylike(fruits, sql2regex(c("%anana%","%grape%"))) ~ "group 2",
      TRUE ~ "group 3"
    )
  )
#      fruits  color   group
# 1     apple    red group 1
# 2 pineapple yellow group 1
# 3     grape purple group 2
# 4   avocado  green group 1
# 5    banana yellow group 2
```

Answer (score 6):

`data.table`'s `like()` function and its `%like%`, `%ilike%`, and `%flike%` operator versions only accept a single pattern parameter but you can use *alternation* in a regular expression. Alternation is expressed by vertical bar:

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
mydata %>%
  mutate(group = ifelse(fruits %ilike% "apple|avocado", "group 1",
                        ifelse(fruits %ilike% "banana|grape", "group 2", "group 3")))
```

> ```
>      fruits  color   group
> 1     apple    red group 1
> 2 pineapple yellow group 1
> 3     grape purple group 2
> 4   avocado  green group 1
> 5    banana yellow group 2
> ```

So, `group 1` matches any string where either `apple` or `avocado` appears *anywhere* in the string. Therefore, `%` to indicate an arbitray number of arbitrary characters is not required.

Note that `%ilike%` has been used instead of `%like%`. `%ilike%` is a new convenience functions which is for case-insensitive pattern matching and which became available with data.table v1.12.4 (on CRAN since 03 Oct 2019).

`%ilike%` will also match the word `Apple` (with a capital `A`).

Of course, `case_when()` is a good alternative to nested `ifelse()` as suggested by [r2evans](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60101961/3817004):

```
mydata %>%
  mutate(group = case_when(fruits %ilike% "apple|avocado" ~ "group 1",
                           fruits %ilike% "banana|grape" ~ "group 2", 
                           TRUE ~ "group 3"))
```

Comment: The "alternation" method works good for me but I discovered the hard way that this notation/syntax does not tolerate any blank whitespace at all !   "apple|avocado" will work fine but "apple | avocado" will not!  Seems a bit strange to me, R normally accepts this ok, any good reason why?

Comment: @JimMaas, the world of regular expressions has its own (sometimes terse) rules. So. `"apple | avocado"` expects a trailing blank after `apple` as well as a leading blank before `avocado`.